# Netezza Does Not Support Correlated Query

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I have the following SQL query:

```
select * from table1 a where 
      a.ORD_EXEC_INST = 'M' and 
      a.evt_ts >= '2016-05-16' and 
      a.evt_ts < '2016-05-17' and
      a.prc = (select mid_pt_prc from table2 where evt_ts <= a.evt_ts order by evt_ts desc limit 1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting
```

I'm not quite sure what this means. Is there any way to re-write this to comply with Netezza?

Comment: Netezza *does* support correlated subqueries:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.0.3/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_correlated_subqueries_ntz_sql.html.

Comment: Perhaps I am using an older version?

Comment: I think it would have to be a pretty old version.